# Viewing Named Object Directories in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, kernel

I'm reading up on the Windows Kernel, where I came upon Named Objects.
The book states that: "Named objects are arranged in hierarchical directories, but the Win32 API restricts user-mode applications’ access to these directories."
Some examples of the directories listed are: "BaseNamedObjects, Devices, Global? ". It seems like it's theoretically possible to look at these directories. Where are these directories located in a Windows machine (XP) and is it possible to get a look inside?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657

Comment: @HarryJohnston , thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. I guess we can't just directly access it from the file browser.

Comment: No; they're not files, after all.